# php get all url variables

Tags: php, get

I'm trying to make links to include the current _GET variables.

Example link: `<a href="?page=2">Page 2</a>`

The current url is: http://example.com/test.php?id=2&a=1

So if someone clicks on the link of page 2 it will take them to:
http://example.com/test.php?id=2&a=1&page=2

Currently if they click on the link it takes them to:
http://example.com/test.php?page=2

As you can see, I need a way to get the current _GET variables in the url and add them to the link. Advice?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The superglobal entry `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` has the query string in it. You could just append that to any further links.

**update:** The alternate response on this page using http_build_query is better because it lets you add new variables to the query string without worrying about extraneous ?s and such. But I'll leave this here because I wanted to mention that you can access the literal query string that's in the current address.

Comment: do you happened to know how to also get the current php page? like if the url is http://example.com/test/page.php it would get the page.php in a variable.

Comment: It's a combination of $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Check out the documentation for [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php); it's groovy, though not the easiest to understand at a glance. You can also learn a lot by running the command `print_r($_SERVER)`. Just remember not to leave it accessible on your website when you're done!

Comment: What is "the colonel's response"? I can't finde any colonel on this page. I guess either the username changed or the answer you are referring to has been removed.

Comment: The user's name is currently "Your Common Sense." At the time he also had a reputation over 100k, which has now been permanently set to 1. I have no idea what the story is there.

Comment: I got the problem that my `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` includes parts **BEFORE** the `?`. Like in `localhost/a/b/file.php?test=test2&a=b` I get `b/file.php?test=test2&a=b`, not even the whole request uri.

Answer (score 14):

```
$new_query_string = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET,array('page' => 2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `@extract($_GET)`. So you can access them directly as variables.

Comment: Don't ever use `extract` on untrusted data. `$_GET` *IS* untrusted data. http://php.net/extract

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you......

```
function get_all_get()
{
        $output = "?"; 
        $firstRun = true; 
        foreach($_GET as $key=>$val) { 
        if($key != $parameter) { 
            if(!$firstRun) { 
                $output .= "&"; 
            } else { 
                $firstRun = false; 
            } 
            $output .= $key."=".$val;
         } 
    } 

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the question above how to include the name of php file as well in the url, using Your Common Sense's perfect method and adding a question mark worked for me:

```
echo "<a href='?".$url."'>link</a>"
```